# Что правильно тестировать в юнит-тестах?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Предположим есть несколько классов A, B и C. Мы тестируем A. Остальные классы - моки. У класса A есть метод, внутри которого он использует B и C, и выдает результат.

Нужно-ли тестировать то, что класс A взаимодействует с B и C, или написать один тест, в котором будет проверяться результат выполнения метода A?

Делать ли такой тест в следующем случае:

```
class A implements B.OnBarCallback {
  private B b;

  public A(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  public void foo() {
    b.bar(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBar() {
    // do something
  }
}

// тест вызова B
void testCallB() {
  B mockB = mock(B.class);
  A a = new A(mockB);
  a.foo();
  verify(mockB).bar(any(OnBarCallback.class));
}

// тест callback
void testACallback() {
  B mockB = mock(B.class);
  A a = new A(mockB);
  a.onBar();
  // do verify something
}
```

Правильно ли вручную дергать метод колбэка в тесте?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если пойти совсем по правилам, то юнит тест должен тестить минимальную единицу кода. У меня есть такое внутреннее правило - если мне вдруг понадобилось продебажить выполнение юнит теста, так как я не понимаю, как оно работает - значит, это не юнит тест, он тестирует слишком большой кусок кода.

Поэтому, если классы В и С достаточно большие и не тривиальные (к примеру, они читают файлы с диска, скачивают с интернета), то лучше их замокать и в классе A тестить с моками. А если методы B/C складывают два числа, то я не вижу особой причины их мокать.

> Нужно-ли тестировать то, что класс A взаимодействует с B и C

Но никто не отменяет тестов взаимодействия классов вместе. Просто это называется уже интеграционные тесты. И они также нужны и полезны.

> или написать один тест, в котором будет проверяться результат выполнения метода A?

А вот сколько тестов написать - это уже философский вопрос. Но одного обычно мало бывает.

Comment: А как поступать если A регается у B как слушатель или callback? Делать тест, который вызовет callback реализацию у A?

Comment: делаете мок для класса А, что бы он когда callback вызовется, выставлял флажок (это может быть поле мока А). А дальше пишеться простой тест, который создает класс мок_А и В, регистрирует мок_А, вызвает нужный метод у В и проверяет, что кол-бек дергнулся. Если нужно проверить, что колбек дернулся с правильными параметрами - мок_А может их все у себя запомнить.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если Вы написали метод foo только для того, что бы потестить, вызывается ли методо bar - то это как то неправильно. Проверить наличие метода не нужно - это работа компилятора. Если же в коде метод foo побольше и реально вызывается - то почему и не протестировать, вызывается ли он. Ведь в реальном коде может быть серия if и тому подобное. Возможно, при каких то условиях колбек и не должен вызываться - это также можно протестировать.

Comment: Вопрос больше в том, что правильно ли из теста вызывать метод колбэка, что бы проверить логику, которая будет выполняться в колбэке. Либо нужно делать так, что бы мок, при регистрации в нем колбэка, сам сразу его дернул, но я считаю, что это как-то неправильно... Что скажете?

Comment: Я не до конца понимаю Ваши мысли, но по моему, правильный ответ будет такой - не нужно тестить то, чего не будет происходить в реальном коде. То есть, если при регистрации кол-бека он не должен вызваться, то и мок класс не должен его вызывать.

Comment: Так как мне тогда проверить колбэк? Например в нем сложная логика.

Comment: Колбек это метод? метод. Значит его можно протестить как метод. И регистрировать его кто-то для этого не нужно.